# I got water on my laptop and the usb ports quit working?

Tags: laptop, usb

I have a BIG problem. Some water has just fallen into my laptop and the USB ports don't work any more.

On Debian I get a number of messages:

```
unable to enumerate USB device on port 1 
unable to enumerate USB device on port 5 
etc.
```

Is any possibility to resurrect the USB ports? On Windows, they don't work either.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use your laptop outside in the rain.

Comment: You did turn the machine off immediately right ? then leave it for about 48 hours in a warm place ?

Comment: Never understood why all Notebook manufacturers don't design the keyboard area to prevent water intrusion to the interior of the notebook, some Lenovo models have this feature, liquids spilled on the keyboard drain out of the bottom of the notebook without getting inside.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unusual for a laptop's keyboard to be connected to the system via USB. What likely happened is that the water ingress caused a short in the keyboard, causing the USB controller to fail and taking the other USB ports with it. Even though USB ports are supposed to be protected against shorts and overcurrent under the USB specification, not every controller has this protection.

Sadly, fixing this would require replacing the keyboard and motherboard.

Answer (score -1):

Never had to face such a situation, see if these links help

- http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/usingyourlaptop/ht/laptopspill.htm
- http://www.ehow.com/tips_113626.html
- http://forums.techguy.org/hardware/835811-solved-water-spilled-laptop-keyboard.html

Comment: thx.. I m going to try it..